# Name of amateur who gave a new proof of the Ramanujan-Nagell theorem?

Tags: ho.history-overview, nt.number-theory, soft-question

In an [article by George Johnson](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/02/09/science/genius-or-gibberish-the-strange-world-of-the-math-crank.html?pagewanted=all) in the New York Times back in 1999, it says that an amateur mathematician from India once sent Ian Stewart a proof of the Ramanujan-Nagell theorem that the Diophantine equation $x^2 + 7 = 2^n$ is solvable if and only if $n = 3, 4, 5, 7, 15$.  The proof "was badly typed on strange paper and cast in an idiosyncratic style that would have given any journal editor the impression that the writer was a crank."  However, it was correct, and after getting some help cleaning it up, the man published the proof.

To me, this is an inspiring story, and I would like to know the name of this man and to see the paper.  I asked Ian Stewart but he said that he remembers the incident but not the identity of the man in question.  I would try asking George Johnson but I am not sure how to contact him.  I searched MathSciNet but was not able to guess which paper it was.

Does anyone know more details?

Comment: Johnson's article is based on the book "Mathematical cranks" by Underwood Dudley. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwood_Dudley Does the book have the name you are looking for? Let me mention that Dudley was sued by one personality mentioned in the book. I remember reading Richard Posner's decision a few years back - it is beautifully worded...

Comment: Unfortunately, *Mathematical Cranks* does not contain the word "Nagell" (according to amazon's search inside the book), so I'm afraid the answer is not there.

Comment: I have no details about this story, but George Johnson has a [homepage](http://sciwrite.org/glj/) which includes his [contact information][2]. You might want to send him an e-mail. (This answer should have been a comment, but I'm unable to post comments just yet) [2]: http://sciwrite.org/glj/email.html

Comment: Having emailed George Johnson, he says that he does not know anything beyond what is said in the article.

Comment: Well, I hope George Johnson was not bothered by the fact that I emailed him as well.  Of course he said the same thing in his reply to me.  I'm wondering, as a matter of general MO etiquette, whether the person who asked the question in the first place should be assumed to be the one to contact a suggested person.  Otherwise the poor recipient may be barraged by a slew of email messages all asking the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to argue that the story is apocryphal; there was no such proof by an amateur.  Here's why

The linked story is not about the amateur and the proof; it's about mathematical cranks.  The amateur is not named; all the article says is

> Several years ago Dr. Stewart heard from a man -- in India again --
>   who had found a new, simpler proof for an obscure, pointless theorem
>   in number theory written by Ramanujan and a collaborator. According to
>   the Ramanujan-Nagell theorem, the only numbers one can square and add
>   7 to, yielding an answer that is a power of 2, are 1, 3, 5, 11 and
>   181. For example, squaring 3 and adding 7 gives 16, which is the fourth power (the square of the square) of 2.
>
> Dr. Stewart was surprised to realize that the proof was correct, but
>   it was badly typed on strange paper and cast in an idiosyncratic style
>   that would have given any journal editor the impression that the
>   writer was a crank. Dr. Stewart advised the writer to find an Indian
>   number theorist who could teach him how to present a proper paper.
>   Several years later the result was published, and soon after came
>   another publication from the same man. ''It is worth reading these
>   things occasionally,'' Dr. Stewart said.

A search on MathSciNet for any article between 1998 and 2003 containing both the words Ramanujan and Nagell turns up only 19 hits.  None are the article in question.

A Google Scholar search with the same parameters turns up only 4 pages of hits.  None are plausibly an article of a proof by one or two authors, (at least one from India)

The 2002 survey article *Relevance of Srinivasa Ramanujan at the dawn of the new millennium* by KS Rao talks about the Ramanujan-Nagell equation does not mention a new proof - one might expect that Rao would have known about this.

---

So what did happen?  Where did the story come from?  One could imagine that Stewart had some conversation with Johnson about mathematical cranks, and misremembered  a story, which Johnson did not do enough checking to correct.  (side note: Johnson writes regularly about science but has only written a couple of math articles)

Comment: When I wrote to Ian Stewart in 2010, he replied, "I recall the incident, but I don't have any information about it any more. We moved building some years ago and a lot got thrown out. Sorry." This neither proves nor disproves your theory but I thought it was worth mentioning. An "intermediate" theory is that everything about the story is correct *except* that the "new" proof of Ramanujan-Nagell turned out to be not so new after all once it was examined by an expert, and so it wasn't published.

Comment: @TimothyChow I like your idea better - it fits all the facts.